# error when fetching IP from geolocation-db.com

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, geolocation, ip

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const get_ip = async () => {
      console.log("got here");
      const response = await fetch("https://geolocation-db.com/json/");
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
    };
    get_ip();
  }, [])
```

This is the error that is printed out:

```
GET https://geolocation-db.com/json/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

What is wrong here? Why can't I fetch the IP from that website?

I can visit it fine in my browser.

Comment: This might be caused by an adblocker.

Comment: Indeed, I do have an adblocker. But why is it that I can visit the website manually and it works?

Comment: I run Imatrix and that website is blocked for a (probably very good) reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GET request is blocked by an adblocker.